# Nuxt 3 + Quill Editor: quill:toolbar Container required for toolbar

Tags: nuxt.js, quill, nuxtjs3, vue-quill-editor

Someone, please help me, for more than 3 hours I am stuck with this problem, I tried using Nuxt 3 and quill editor with the customized toolbar, here is the code

html

```
<client-only>
   <QuillEditor
      theme="snow"
      ref="quill"
      contentType="html"
      :options="editorOption"
      toolbar="#toolbar"
      v-model:content="forms.content"
   />
</client-only>
```

js

```
data(){
   return {
     editorOption: {
        theme: "snow",
        placeholder: "Write something...",
        modules: {
          toolbar: "#toolbar"
        },
     },
   }
}
```

THE ERROR

```
quill:toolbar Container required for toolbar 

{
    "container": "#toolbar",
    "handlers": {}
}

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook 
  at <QuillEditor theme="snow" ref="quill" contentType="html"
```

Comment: Try to add a `<div>` around `<QuillEditor>`.

Comment: thanks for your advice, still does not work.

Comment: How did you imported Quill? Got something in their Github issues?

Comment: [https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1641](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1641)

I have tried many, but still does not work. The error only when I used the customized toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Vue Quill is expecting you to define [your custom toolbar](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/toolbar.html#custom-toolbar-container). That error happens when you define a custom toolbar selector '#toolbar' but don't actually put the toolbar anywhere (it is looking for an element with an id of "toolbar").

Answer (score -1):

The main reason to this could be due to the fact that when ssr is used, Nuxt tried to render in server-side but it does not exist.
Moreover, I am not really sure if quill will support Vite at the moment so I suggest using packages like vue3-quill-editor-vite.

Comment: That one should be a comment.